# Change certain characters on every file in every subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm attempting to create a script that changes certain letters in all files inside subdirectories. This is what I'm trying to execute and it's not working:

```
for f in *;                
do  rename 's/ó/o/g' *;
    rename 's/ú/u/g' *;
    rename 's/á/a/g' *;
    rename 's/é/e/g' *;
    rename 's/í/i/g' *;
    rename 's/ñ/n/g' *;
done
```

Comment: You don't need a loop if you want to operate on all files and directories in the current directory. How isn't it working - files don't get renamed? Do you want to run it recursively? What implementation of `rename` are you using - post output of `rename --version`.

Comment: I indeed want to change those characters on everything (files, directories, subdirectories), my rename version is 1.601. When I run it the names are not changed, I was using rename `'s/ó/o/g' * -v;` to see what happened and I got not results

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you are using Perl implementation of `rename` program
(there is another program called `rename` which is a part of
`util-linux` package):

```
shopt -s globstar
rename 's/ó/o/g' **/*
rename 's/ú/u/g' **/*
rename 's/á/a/g' **/*
rename 's/é/e/g' **/*
rename 's/í/i/g' **/*
rename 's/ñ/n/g' **/*
shopt -u globstar
```

You can also chain replacements in one command if you find it more
readable:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -v \
    's/ó/o/g ; \
    s/ú/u/g ; \
    s/á/a/g ; \
    (...)' **/*
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try this solution and provide my feedback about it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using zsh on macOS Big Sur 11.6 I'm getting a `zsh: command not found: shopt` message after running the script and I was not able to install short via Brew